# How do I know the structure of a tuple?

Tags: scala, tuples

In the following Tuple in Scala :

> Array[(String, (String, String))] =
>   Array((2828,(7097,2828,403,1,129.99,129.99,2828,2013-08-10
>   00:00:00.0,4952,SUSPECTED_FRAUD)),
>   (37231,(92926,37231,191,3,299.97,99.99,37231,2014-03-11
>   00:00:00.0,4470,PENDING)),

You can see that the second tuple(String, String) contains two separate string values. However, I cannot determine how is the tuple partitioned by looking at

> :(7097,2828,403,1,129.99,129.99,2828,2013-08-10
>   00:00:00.0,4952,SUSPECTED_FRAUD)

i.e. How can I know which one is the ._2._1 value and which one is ._2._2 value?

Comment: You can't, with this string representation. You need to print this with your own function, use different separators or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your own print function like this:

```
val array = Array(("2828",("7097,2828,403,1,129.99,129.99,2828,2013-08-10 00:00:00.0,4952","SUSPECTED_FRAUD")), ("37231",("92926,37231,191,3,299.97,99.99,37231,2014-03-11 00:00:00.0","4470,PENDING")))

array.foreach{case (first, (second, third)) =>
  println(first)
  println(second)
  println(third)
  println("-------------")
}
/*
2828
7097,2828,403,1,129.99,129.99,2828,2013-08-10 00:00:00.0,4952
SUSPECTED_FRAUD
-------------
37231
92926,37231,191,3,299.97,99.99,37231,2014-03-11 00:00:00.0
4470,PENDING
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!